# Adjustment of title of chapter in extbook

Tags: chapters, titles, extbook

I want my chapter title look like this:

[image: intro1]

I have this so far:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=czech,slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\centering\bfseries\Huge}
  {} {} {}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

I want to add `\hrulefill` somehow.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Using `\hrulefill`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=czech,slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  {}{0pt}
  {\hrulefill\\[0.4ex]} % The top rule
  [\vspace{0.1ex}\hrulefill] % The bottom rule

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the `0.4ex` space before and after the title as needed.

Or you can use `\titlerule`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=czech,slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  {}{0pt}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filcenter}
  [\vspace{1ex}{\titlerule}]

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This styles chapter titles with `\titlerule` for horizontal lines above and below, and `\vspace{1ex}` for space around the centered title. Adjust `\titlerule[1pt]` and `\vspace` values for custom spacing and line thickness.

Comment: Great idea, many thanks ♥